# Initiate Properties automatically using StructureMap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, winforms, asp.net-mvc-2, structuremap

If i have N numbers of classes on each of them i am declaring for example property which contains some app setting values from config file.

```
  public static IAppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }
```

I want to populate this property automatically when class is created.

I am thinking to achieve this goal using StructureMap.

I want to "say" somehow only in one place, that if class contain this property populate it.

May be some one came across this and have any ideas?

ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC, ConsoleApp/WinForms

Answer (score 0):

> If i have N numbers of classes on each
>   of them i am declaring for example
>   property which contains some app
>   setting values from config file.

You should consider having those N classes derive from a base class which contains this property:

```
public abstract Base
{
    public IAppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }
}
```

then if you want to have this property automatically populated by StructureMap you should no longer instantiate them manually but always ask the container for a value.

For example in a ASP.NET MVC application I would use constructor injection to pass the value of `IAppSettings` to all the controllers that need it.

Comment: I think i am looking for something like that http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/property-injection but i cant get it work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a variation of the SettingsScanner described in this post: http://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2009/07/13/how-we-handle-application-configuration/

You can get the full code for the scanner and ISettingsProvider from The FubuMVC source code:
https://github.com/DarthFubuMVC/fubumvc/blob/2e7ea30391eac0053300ec0f6f63136503b16cca/src/FubuMVC.StructureMap/SettingsScanner.cs